# How to completely delete database in Neo4j 4.x?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am trying to load the database from csvs using `neo4j-admin load`. If I delete the existing database and load data again using `neo4j-admin load`, it does not load the data. Steps:

1. Load database using `neo4j-admin load` to database `temp`
2. Delete database directory `data/databases/temp` from neo4j
3. Reload csvs to database `temp` using `neo4j-admin load`, successfully loads the data
4. Restart db

At `localhost:7474`, the database is empty, no nodes or relationships. The version of Neo4j is 4.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using CE neo4j then to delete the database completely delete the directory `data/transactions/<db_name>` along with `data/databases/<db_name>`

Comment: That works! Probably best to create a script if needed often

Comment: Yes, agreed. I have shell script which deletes both dirs with db_name as an argument. And I add it bash_profile with command so I can call it from anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Did you stop and delete the database in the systemdb too?

:use system
Stop database temp;
Drop database temp;

Delete directory

And then after you have loaded it again with neo4j-admin load

Create database temp

Also make  sure it has started And look at the online column of

Show databases

Comment: Can't delete the database using `:use system stop database temp; drop database temp;` command. It still list temp databse in `show databases`. Even deleting the directory of temp database and restarting the db don't remove the db from `show databases` list and creates a directory of temp db automatically. Don't know if this helps, but I am using a community edition of Neo4j 4.0 which only allow one user database, so I change the default database name `dbms.default_database=schoolmatesmall` in configuration(`neo4.conf`) if I want to load temp database and not the default neo4j.

Comment: Command for stopping or deleting other database(temp or any other non-default database or any offline database than one which is loaded) returns error `Unsupported administration command`. Is it because of community edition limit of only one user database?

Comment: Yes. That’s the current limit in CE. You can use EE in Neo4j Desktop, Sandbox and in the startup program